# Errors in the Java URLConnection Class

Tags: java, android-studio

I recently updated to android studio 4 and I’ve been going through the URL and `URLConnection` Classes
And I've noticed there are several errors they all originally come from the imports

```
import sun.security.util.SecurityConstansts;
import sun.net.www.MessageHeader;
```

The compiler cannot resolve those two classes although they do exist.

Is there anything I should do about it?

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/faq-sun-packages.html

Comment: @hfontanez - I think the OP is seeing these errors in relation to classes in the JDK, not to their own code.

Comment: @Steve OP wrote "The compiler cannot resolve those two classes although they do exist." You cannot import those classes directly anymore; hence my previous comment.